# pyspark UDF with null values check and if statement

Tags: pyspark

This works provided no null values exist in an array passed to a pyspark UDF.

```py
concat_udf = udf(
    lambda con_str, arr: [x + con_str for x in arr], ArrayType(StringType())
)
```

I am not seeing how we can adapt this with a null / None check with an If. How to adapt the following correctly below that does not work:

```
concat_udf = udf(lambda con_str, arr: [  if x is None: 'XXX' else: x + con_str for x in arr  ], ArrayType(StringType()))
```

I can find no such example. if with `transform` no success either.

```
+----------+--------------+--------------------+
|      name|knownLanguages|          properties|
+----------+--------------+--------------------+
|     James| [Java, Scala]|[eye -> brown, ha...|
|   Michael|[Spark, Java,]|[eye ->, hair -> ...|
|    Robert|    [CSharp, ]|[eye -> , hair ->...|
|Washington|          null|                null|
| Jefferson|        [1, 2]|                  []|
+----------+--------------+--------------------+
```

should become

```
+----------+--------------------+-----------------------+
|      name|knownLanguages|          properties         |
+----------+--------------------+-----------------------+
|     James| [JavaXXX, ScalaXXX]|[eye -> brown, ha...   |
|   Michael|[SparkXXX, JavaXXX,XXX]|[eye ->, hair -> ...|
|    Robert|    [CSharpXXX, XXX]|[eye -> , hair ->...   |
|Washington|                 XXX|                null   |
| Jefferson|        [1XXX, 2XXX]|                  []   |
+----------+--------------+-----------------------------+
```

Comment: [Ternary Operators](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/ternary_operators.html#ternary-operators)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using ternary operator, I would do something like this :

```py
concat_udf = udf(
    lambda con_str, arr: [x + con_str if x is not None else "XXX" for x in arr]
    if arr is not None
    else ["XXX"],
    ArrayType(StringType()),
)

# OR 

concat_udf = udf(
    lambda con_str, arr: [
        x + con_str if x is not None else "XXX" for x in arr or [None]
    ],
    ArrayType(StringType()),
)
```

Comment: PythonException: An exception was thrown from a UDF: 'TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable'

Comment: @thebluephantom which one supposed to be None ? the array or the content of the array ? This error means `arr` is None. But you wrote a test case on `x` in your question.

Comment: missing the else on 2nd one. very finnicky this udf with pyspark

Comment: Edited, that should clarify.

Comment: @thebluephantom Check the edit. It is always the same logic.